# In 3.5, do ranger spells count as arcane spells or divine spells?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

As far as usage goes, do ranger abilities with magic count as arcane or divine?

Answer (score 11):

**A rangers spells are Divine.**

From the [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/ranger.htm):

> Beginning at 4th level, a ranger gains the ability to cast a small number of **divine spells**, which are drawn from the ranger spell list.  A ranger must choose and prepare his spells in advance (see below).
>
> Like other spellcasters, a ranger can cast only a certain number of spells of each spell level per day. ... In addition, he receives bonus spells per day if he has a high Wisdom score.
>
> A ranger prepares and casts spells the way a cleric does, though he cannot lose a prepared spell to cast a cure spell in its place. A ranger may prepare and cast any spell on the ranger spell list, provided that he can cast spells of that level, but he must choose which spells to prepare during his daily meditation.
>
> Through 3rd level, a ranger has no caster level. At 4th level and higher, his caster level is one-half his ranger level.

So, Divine.